# $_POST only receives default value from select control

Tags: php, html, select, post

I have a select control that will load next to each user and the value defaults to which floor that user is located on based on the result from the MySQL Database. Whomever is editing the list can change which floor that user is located on and submit the change to push to the database. However when I receive the $_POST['selFloor'] value it is always whichever the default selected value is. No matter if the user changes it or not.

```
<?php
$floors = array('1st'=>"First",  
            '2nd'=>"Second",  
            '3rd'=>"Third",  
            '4th'=>"Fourth",  
            '5th'=>"Fifth",  
            '6th Control'=>"Sixth");

$query = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY name asc";
$result = $db->query($query);       
$i = 0;

while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$i++;
echo '<select name="field['.$i.'][floor]"';
    foreach($floors as $key=>$val) {
        echo ($key == $row['floor']) ? "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"$key\">$val</option>":"<option value=\"$key\">$val</option>";
    }
echo '</select>';
} ?>
```

A sample of the select control. If the $row['floor'] returns ['1st'] it will make that option the selected value, but once the user changes it to '2nd' and hits submit, $_POST only see's the select value for whichever option has the selected argument.

```
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            foreach($val as $subkey => $sub) {
                        echo $sub['floor'] // Outputs first option that got selected set
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML Output of Select:

```
<select name="field[1][floor]">
<option value="1st">First</option>
<option value="2nd">Second</option>
<option selected="selected" value="3rd">Third</option>
<option value="4th">Fourth</option>
<option value="5th">Fifth</option>
<option value="6th">Sixth</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what about your <select> tag?

Comment: If every user's `select` is named `selFloor` that will be your problem.

Comment: What is $row['floor']?

Comment: No, they are named separately. I just simplified it for the example.

    `name="field['.$i.'][floor]"`
Where $i is $i++ after every loop to make each select unique.

Comment: $row['floor] is returned from:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY name asc";
$result = $db->query($query);      while ($row = $result->fetch_array())`

Comment: @Sirhiro Can you show HTML for this select, that is generated for example, when $row['floor'] = '3rd'?

Comment: @user4035 Okay, I have added it to the original post.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the said behaviour based on this code, so I think the root of the problem lies elsewhere. Try it in another browser.

Comment: @tzunghaor You are correct. I prematurely posted this question before fully reviewing my code. I had a duplicate element, a hidden input that was named the same as the select. So it was returning the default floor over the selected option every time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any errors in your HTML, except for the fact, that you are checking $_POST['selFloor'], while the name of select is field[1][floor]. Try to change it to 'selFloor':

```
echo '<select name="selFloor">';
...
```

And I don't see closing angle bracket (`>`) for select.

Answer (score 0):

Because each one of your `<option>` menus has a `selected` attribute, the browser doesn't know which one is selected even though it is firing the `change` event.

Try placing the `selected` attribute on the first `<option>` only.

```
<?php
    foreach($floors as $key=>$val) {
        // if first, place selected attribute
        echo ($key == $row['floor']) 
           ? "<option value=\"$key\">$val</option>" // selected att was removed
           :"<option value=\"$key\">$val</option>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This isn't it. Now your If statement performs no function because there's no difference between each echo. And the Floor won't always be first, it could be 2nd-6th.

The left echo provides the selected attribute if it matches the floor while the right does not. Both sides do not apply a selected argument because only one will be equal to the floor.